# Quotient Space Injectivity Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> $3.90$ **Definition** $\tilde T$
>   Suppose $T\in\mathcal L(V,W)$. Define $\tilde T:V/({\rm null}~T)\to W$ by $\tilde T(v+{\rm null}~T)=Tv$

---

> $3.91$ **Null space and range of $\tilde T$**
>   Suppose $T\in\mathcal L(V,W)$. Then
>
> 1. $\tilde T$ is a linear map from $V/({\rm null}~T)$ to $W$;
> 2. $\tilde T$ is injective;
> 3. ${\rm range}~\tilde T={\rm range}~T$;
> 4. $V/({\rm null}~T)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm range}~T$.

*Proof*

1. The rountine verification that $\tilde T$ is linear is left ot the reader.
2. Suppose $v\in V$ and $\tilde T(v+{\rm null}~T)=0$. Then $Tv=0$. Thus $v\in{\rm null}~T$. Hence $3.85$ implies $v+{\rm null}~T=0+{\rm null}~T$. This implies that ${\rm null}~\tilde T=0$, and hence $\tilde T$ is injective, as desired.
3. The definition of $\tilde T$ shows that ${\rm range}~\tilde T={\rm range}~T$.
4. Parts 2. and 3. imply that if we think of $\tilde T$ as mapping into ${\rm range}~T$, then $\tilde T$ is an isomorphism from $V/({\rm null}~T)$ onto ${\rm range}~T$.

In part 2. I understand that $v + \operatorname{null} T = 0 + \operatorname{null} T$, but I don't understand how this implies that $\operatorname{null} \tilde T = 0$?

Comment: Any congruence class (modulo $\ker T$) which belongs to the kernel of $\widetilde{\mkern2mu T\mkern-2mu} \,$ is the congruence class of $0$.

Comment: Sorry maybe silly question but does this mean v = 0 ?

Comment: No, it only means $v\in\ker T$.

Comment: $v$ is not an element of $V/\operatorname{null}(T)$, but $v + \operatorname{null}(T)$ is

Comment: Sorry is there another way to explain this, I have not learned congruence classes yet.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe changing notation will help you see it clearer. If $$[v]=v+{\rm null}(T),$$
then $[v]=[w]$ if and only if $v+{\rm null}(T)=w+{\rm null}(T)$ and $${\rm null}(\widetilde{T})=\{[v]\mid v \in V\}.$$By showing that $\widetilde{T}[v]=Tv=0$ implies $v+{\rm null}(T)=0+{\rm null}(T)$ you are showing that $[v]\in {\rm null}(\widetilde{T})$ implies $[v]=[0]$. In other words, ${\rm null}(\widetilde{T})=\{[0]\}$. So $\widetilde{T}$ is injective.

Comment: So when they wrote null(T ˜ )= 0 they meant null(T ˜ )= 0 + null(T) ?

Comment: No. ${\rm null}(\widetilde{T})$ is a subspace of $V/{\rm null}(T)$, while $0+{\rm null}(T)$ is an element.

Comment: Then what exactly is [0] ?

Comment: They're abusing notation using $0$ to denote the zero subspace, the zero vector in $V$, and the zero vector in the quotient space. You have that $0_{V/{\rm null}(T)}=0_V+{\rm null}(T)$ and ${\rm null}(\widetilde{T})=\{0_{V/{\rm null}(T)}\}$.

Comment: I said it was only an alternative notation and what exactly I meant by $[v]$ for any $v$. Make $v=0$ to see that $[0]=0+{\rm null}(T)$.